# error setting up a menu class

Tags: java, android, menu

the below block throws an error while setting up a new menu in android

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String ncall = Classes[position];
    try {
        Class ourClass=Class.forName("com.example.newtrynow.", + ncall );
 \\above line shows error, why is "+" not supported its just appending the rest of string
        Intent ourIntent=new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma from the following line

```
Class ourClass=Class.forName("com.example.newtrynow.", + ncall );
```

It should be like this

```
  Class ourClass=Class.forName("com.example.newtrynow." + ncall );
```

Comment: wat does the parameter password do in a textview? android:password